# NancyFx: @Each, @Current, and @EndEach fails Razor compilation but @Model.Property is fine

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

How can I fix this and make my .cshtml compile?

**Summarize the problem**
I have an existing NancyFX 1.4.4 web application that uses Razor. It is working. I added a List of objects to my existing Model and referenced the List in my .cshtml file using @Model.Things, @Each.Model.Things, @Current.Property1, and @EndEach, but my .cshtml's Razor compilation fails with these errors:

- [CS0103] Line: 380 Column: 24 - The name 'Each' does not exist in the
  current context (show)
- [CS0103] Line: 381 Column: 83 - The name 'Current' does not exist in the current context (show)
- [CS0103] Line: 382 Column: 24 - The name 'EndEach' does not exist in the current context (show)

**Provide details and any research**

- I added this to my .cshtml, which does not error,

  alert("@Model.Things");

  and displays:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.Thing]

- This is the .cshtml code that causes the compilation error:

  @Each.Model.Things
  <option value="@Current.Property1">blah</option>
  @EndEach

**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

- I downloaded the Super Simple View Engine from [Nancy's github repo](https://github.com/thecodejunkie/Nancy/tree/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.SuperSimpleViewEngine). It uses @Each.Users, @Current.Name, and @EndEach. It works fine.
- I changed the List in my Model to IEnumerable and made no difference.
- I put a breakpoint in my server-side Module to ensure there were objects in the List.
- I checked my app.config and web.config for Razor references. Razor is working, so I didn't think that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not Razor elements. They are defined in the [Super-Simple-View-Engine](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine) itself. See the @Current definition in [SuperSimpleViewEngine.cs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/v1.4.4/src/Nancy/ViewEngines/SuperSimpleViewEngine/SuperSimpleViewEngine.cs) and its usage in the [SuperSimpleViewEngine demo](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/v1.4.4/src/Nancy.Demo.SuperSimpleViewEngine).